# where do i set Image Labels in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magmi

in the link: `https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor`

**It has given as:**

```
To set base image labels
image_label (label to use for image)
small_image_label (label to use for small_image)
thumbnail_label (label to use for thumbnail image)
```

**A) What are Image labels?**

**B) Where should I set it?**

**BTW, below are my feed column names:**

```
store,websites,type,attribute_set,is_affiliate_product,status,visibility,qty,is_in_stock,tax_class_id,weight,name,meta_keyword,description,sku,manufacturer,price,merchant_buy_link,remote_image_url,main_category,color,for,shoe_type,short_description,remote_thumbnail_image_url,category_ids,merchant_name,merchant_id,small_image
```

**Below is 1 row sample data"**

```
admin,base,simple,Affiliate Product,1,Enabled,"Catalog, Search",1,1,None,1,Ed Hardy Girls Bird Flower Cap - White,"handbags, wallets, designer handbags, prada, gucci, burberry",The  Ed Hardy&nbsp;Girls Bird Flower Cap  is an adorable cap for little girl.&nbsp;This cap features front tattoo  Bird Flower  graphics Embroidered print  adjustable Back  It also has printed text graphics with the words &#34; Ed Hardy &#34;. Your little,F58-EH5GH124UBRD,Ed Hardy,11.99,http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-6521002-10569016?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fashion58.com%2Fitemdetail.asp%3Fmod%3DEH5GH124UBRD,http://www.fashion58.com/itemimages/5GH124UBRD.jpg,Hats & Caps > Caps,White,,,The  Ed Hardy&nbsp;Girls Bird Flower Cap  is an adorable cap for little girl.&nbsp;This cap features front tattoo  Bird Flower  graphics Embroidered print  adjustable Back  It also has printed text graphics with the words &#34; Ed Hardy &#34;. Your little,http://www.fashion58.com/itemimages/5GH124UBRD.jpg,73,Fashion58,123,
```

**C) Anything wrong in column names or sample data?**

**D) Iam unable to display product remote images in my site.. iam sure iam doing something wrong with Magmi.**

pls kindly tell me..

Comment: Why are you asking the same question multiple times?  Please refrain from repeating your question and contain it to one.

Comment: for B) i get image from remote , so what to set it in csv file?

Comment: Joey.  It's written in the Magmi documentation.  You set the URL of the image you are trying to assign to that image.  Furthermore, you're spamming this community with repeated comments and questions which is annoying to those who are trying to help you.

Comment: @Axel : iam sorry i asked wrong, my query is: Could you please tell me how to set "Base Image values" in csv file? iam really unable to download images from remote, thats why made me to ask again and again.. pls dnt think me wrong! Does base image values are URL's?

Comment: I had remote image urls in my feed.. i even used plugin image processer, but even then my remote iamges are not getting downloaded into media/import and display images in my site.. iam really frustrated this issue.

Comment: Is it solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A)** Image labels is the Image Title 
( for example you have multiple images for the product, 1 from the front and from the back and from the side, so you put label to display in the website so the people can understand whats this picture, like front view of the product, side view etc.. )

**B)** You can set it in the csv file you will import or from the backend manage products -> edit  -> images gallery tab

**C)** (the file should be normal CSV file, no big deal) No one able to tell if the feed is right! because some times it depends on your magmi configuration ! so try to import sample file and see the errors magmi output also check if the products are fine.

**D)** As far as i know Magmi doesn't support remote images, so you need to write small php script to get the images and save it in your disk then upload it in your server and put the path for magmi to use !

Comment: for B) i get image from remote , so what to set it in csv file?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me. The row sample data does not delimit correctly. One or more columns use one or more commas and double quotes. Import the data into excel or a gsheet and read over it carefully as i did with my data. Ensure the correct data is in the correct column and try again.